# Слово "боярин"

Tags: этимология

Какое происхождение у слова "боярин" и происходит ли от него слово "барин"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Барин, разумеется, исходно - фонетический вариант "боярин".
Боярин - от общеславянского "болярин" - вельможа. 
Происхождение "болярин" темно, возможно связано с тюркским "bai", "bei" - знатный, уважаемый.

Answer (score 1):

"Происхождение "болярин" темно"

Разве? *Более ярый (яркий)*. Или даже *ярый в бою*, а "л" сюда затесался потому что русский язык плохо переносит два гласных подряд... Не?
*Вельможа* - *вельми могущественный*, кто *много может*.

Answer (score 0):

В поддержку варианта болярин -> боярин говорит тот факт, что в сербском языке најбољи обозначает лучшие. Т. е. бояре - это элита по-современному.