# Слово Боярин. От чего произошло?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Слово Боярин разбирают по разному. Самые популярные смыслыэтого слова :
1 В бою ярый 
2 большой знатный муж
Наткнулся на ролик, где вроде бы логично выводится это слово со смыслом Большой (Бо- Бол) землевладелец (Ар - Арин).Похоже что это 3 альтернативная версия.
Что вы думаете по этому поводу ? Какая из версий более логична ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv9fiOZf2JE&t=1s

Comment: И еще вот здесь есть ответы: _Слово “боярин”_ https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd

Answer (score -1):

Боярин<болярин - от "бояр" - тюркское слово.

Не надо ничего разбирать. "Бояр" - основа русским языком цельнозаимствованная.

Вот что оно значило в тюркских - это вопрос интересный, хотя и не имеет к русскому языку прямого отношения. Скорее всего орождено "bai+är", где bai - знатный, сановный, är - персонифицирующий суффикс. То есть - вельможа, господин.

Подробнее - у Фасмера.
https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-1155.htm

Comment: Что такое «цельнозаимствованное» слово и откуда в тюркских языках славянский суффикс -ин-? Почему вы безапелляционно утверждаете о тюркском происхождении, когда современная точка зрения на этот вопрос гораздо многогранней (см. хотя бы работы Хелимского)? Почему вы считаете _боярин_, происходящим из _болярин_?

Comment: *откуда в тюркских языках славянский суффикс -ин-* - Я не могу ответить на ваш вопрос. Потрудитесь сформулировать его внятно. Или хотя бы представить доказательства того, что этот суффикс в тюркских присутствует. Иначе это разговор совершенно умозрительный.

Comment: *Почему вы безапелляционно утверждаете о тюркском происхождении* - потому что не считаю необходимым упоминать заведомо абсурдные версии. Я не вступаю в полемику с носителями народной этимологии, а отвечаю на вопрос с научной точки зрения как я её понимаю.

Comment: *Почему вы считаете боярин, происходящим из болярин?* - потому, что это более древняя форма. Или вы ставите под сомнене даже родственность этих форм?

Comment: Это уж вы утверждаете, что слово _боярин_ «цельнозаимствованное», то есть _целиком_ заимствовано из тюркских. С суффиксом -ин-. Мне как раз это совершенно непонятно. То, что вы говорите о «научной точки зрения», увы, некорректно хотя в том плане, что нужно бы упоминать другие точки зрения, между прочим, поддерживаемые ведущими исследователями (например, Аникиным). Иначе вы излагаете не «научную точку зрения», а свой вольный рассказ о том, что когда-то было написано учеными.

Comment: *Что такое «цельнозаимствованное» слово*  - слово, которое заимствованно целиком и таким образом не подлежит морфемному разложению.  Остальное - у Фасмера. Очень хочу увидеть точку зрения некоего Хелимского. Если это тот, который сильно спекулировал на недоказанной нострической теории, то будет особенно интеерсно услышать о его многогранности.

Comment: *Это уж вы утверждаете, что слово боярин «цельнозаимствованное», то есть целиком заимствовано из тюркских.* Простите, я такого не говорил. Уточнил, что речь об основе "бояр".

Comment: Я ничего не говорил о родственности форм _болярин_ и _боярин_; объяснение _л_ -- спорный сложный момент, и я соглашаюсь с аргументацией, согласно которой _л_ -- результат контаминации с _bol'-_ (ср. _больше_).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108362/discussion-between-behemothus-and-aer).

Answer (score -1):

Слово древнее, индоевропейского происхождения.
В санскритском словаре:
"bharga" - великолепие
"bhartA" - муж
"bhAryа" - воин, солдат, наёмник
"bhara" - битва, война
"barhis" - великолепный
"bharma" - плата, золото
"bharti" - держать, править, обладать
"bhartR" - муж, господин, глава